# How to find out the chipset of my Router?

Tags: debian, wifi, router

Trying to install wifi on my fresh debian I got confused.
It seems to be more complex than I thought.
As far as I understood it correct I need to manually download drivers for my router, that depend on his chipset. How to find out the chipset of the router?

I have a fritz!Box 7430.

**Note**

```
$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A3

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260) [8086:1010]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ uname -a

Linux debian-sgtechedge 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Welcome, you need to install the driver for you wifi card ,not the router. To know the wifi card details please add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3` and `uname -a`

Comment: @GAD3R then I misuderstood the guides. Ive added the execution of the commands in the description.

Comment: See the [installation guide](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Installation) , replace `stretch` by `buster` .

Comment: @GAD3R thanks so much. It helped. I would like to accept your answer, but I cant accept your comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the wifi driver for the *Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260*, follow the [installation guide](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Installation) on debian wiki (replace `stretch` by `buster`):

> Add a `non-free` component to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, for example:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
```

> Update the list of available packages and install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

> As the `iwlwifi` module is automatically loaded for supported devices, reinsert this module to access installed firmware:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```